# Reference request about equivalence of automata / regular expressions up-to a language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, reference-request, regular-expressions

The most widely used notion of equivalence of regular expressions
$r_1$ and $r_2$, or finite state automata ${A}_1$ and ${A}_2$ resp., over an alphabet $\Sigma$, is to consider their languages: we can define

$$r_1 \cong r_2 
\qquad\text{iff}\qquad
 \mathsf{language}(r_1) = \mathsf{language}(r_2)
$$
and likewise for  ${A}_1 \cong {A}_2$.
My question is about a natural generalisation: fix a set $S$ and define

$$r_1 \cong_{S} r_2
\qquad \text{iff} \qquad
 \mathsf{language}(r_1)\cap S = \mathsf{language}(r_2) \cap S$$

I call this *"equivalence-up-to $S$"*. Clearly $\cong$, the standard equivalence, arises as special case with  $S = \Sigma^*$. Equivalence-up-to a set is a natural and versatile construction, not restricted to regular languages, and I've seen it used before.

**Question:** Where can I find equivalence-up-to a set in older papers? Does it have a name,  can it be found
in one of the well-known textbooks on automata theory?